# How to use inline svg in CSS in Angular6

Tags: angular, svg, build

I have used following css in Angular6 Project.

```
.bg
{
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' width=\'28\' height=\'49\' viewBox=\'0 0 28 49\'%3E%3Cg fill-rule=\'evenodd\'%3E%3Cg id=\'hexagons\' fill=\'%23ff6576\' fill-opacity=\'1\' fill-rule=\'nonzero\'%3E%3Cpath d=\'\'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}
```

When I try to build the project it throws following error:

```
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: Can't resolve '%27data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns=/%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/%27%20fill=/%27%23fff/%27%20viewBox=/%270%200%208%208/%27%3E%3Cpath%20d...
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Solution (From @Mathias):

```
.bg
{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='28' height='49' viewBox='0 0 28 49'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg id='hexagons' fill='%23ff6576' fill-opacity='1' fill-rule='nonzero'%3E%3Cpath d=''/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Comment: Did you try double quotes around the outside and single on the inside? (just a quick guess)

Comment: Thanks @Mathias, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quotes around the outside and single on the inside

Answer (score 2):

You can try to Double quotes around the outside and single on the inside

```
.bg
{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' width=\'28\' height=\'49\' viewBox=\'0 0 28 49\'%3E%3Cg fill-rule=\'evenodd\'%3E%3Cg id=\'hexagons\' fill=\'%23ff6576\' fill-opacity=\'1\' fill-rule=\'nonzero\'%3E%3Cpath d=\'\'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Comment: Escaping inner single quotes not needed anymore